# What should i do if it occurs to me that, i have probably made mistake in the previous salah?

Tags: salat

I was just performing Isha, and while on the Witr it occured to me that, I've probably skipped the second rakah on the Sunnah? Because I couldn't remember what surah I recited on the second rakah of sunnah.

So should I restart from the sunnah? What if I did perform the salah accordingly, just couldn't remember and from doubt I performed again? Will both be accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform two prosternations after giving the last salutation of your salah when you doubt the validity of it.

> Narrated Abdullah ibn Ja'far:
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: Anyone who is in doubt in his prayer should make two prostrations after giving the salutation.

If you stood up and left the place of your salah, then repeat the salah.

May Allah guide us all.